# GUI software to control applications' internet usage

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, internet, gui

I need a decent GUI software to **control** (set upload and download limits) the internet usage of applications dynamically.

For example I want to limit google chrome's bandwidth to not go beyond 10Kbps download. Half an hour later I want to remove the limit. Two hours later I decide to set the up & down limits to 20Kbps. 3 hrs later remove the limit...

Note that `trickle` does exactly what I want but the problem is that you need to **start** the program with trickle. I want to **dynamically** set limits for my applications and **not have to start & restart** the app every time I want to change the limits. Kind of like how ktorrent does limiting.

*Think of the scenario where you want to play DotA 2 but you experience lags because your connection is slow so whenever you want to play the game you want to give the game all your bandwidth to reduce the lag as much as you can*

Comment: I'm not sure if it's even technically possible to restrict bandwidth for an application, and modify those limits _while it's running_, unless the app is built to support that like ktorrent.. That said, are you downloading things with chrome ? You might want to try a dedicated download manager / accelerator, such as [uGet](http://ugetdm.com/).

Comment: It's not about accelerating a download. It's more about gaming. But how come is it not technically possible? thx @JonasCz

Comment: It _might_ be possible, but I don't know how and have never heard of this being done. As to the download manager: I forgot to mention that this will allow you to pause downloads, set speed limits as needed, any time, and so on, which may be better than trying to get chrome to do so, if that's what you're trying to do.